# Why do I get a `Unknown option: .babelrc.presets` error when trying to transpile my code using babel-cli v6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs, babel-cli

I have this in my `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "babel-cli": "^6.8.0",
  "babel-core": "^6.8.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.5.0",
  ...
}
```

And this in my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "es2015",
    "stage-2"
  ]
}
```

When running `babel --source-maps=true --out-dir=lib src` I get this:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/babel --source-maps=true --out-dir=lib src

ReferenceError: [BABEL] src/main.js: Unknown option: /dev/my-project/.babelrc.presets
```

I have `babel-cli` 6, so why doesn't it recognize `.babelrc.presets`?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question because I was trying to solve this for a while and I thought it might be helpful for others:

The problem was a known npm v3 bug. Unlike npm v2, npm v3 will flatten the dependency tree, so there was a deep dependency in my project that was including babel v5 and npm was linking the binary to my `./node_modules/.bin` directory, overwriting the binary coming from my `devDependency` (`"babel-cli": "^6.8.0"`).

The fix is to rebuild this package once `npm install` has finished. You should add this to your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "postinstall": "npm rebuild babel-cli",
  ...
}
```